# Autonumber value of last inserted row - MS Access / VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, jet

I have a `JET` table with an auto-number as the primary key, and I would like to know how I can retrieve this number after inserting a row.  I have thought of using `MAX()` to retrieve the row with the highest value, but am not sure how reliable this would be.  Some sample code:

```
Dim query As String
Dim newRow As Integer
query = "INSERT INTO InvoiceNumbers (date) VALUES (" & NOW() & ");"
newRow = CurrentDb.Execute(query)
```

Now I know that this wouldn't work, since `Execute()` won't return the value of the primary key, but this is basically the kind of code I am looking for.  I will need to use the primary key of the new row to update a number of rows in another table.

What would be the simplest / most readable way of doing this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If `DAO` use

```
RS.Move 0, RS.LastModified
lngID = RS!AutoNumberFieldName
```

If `ADO` use

```
cn.Execute "INSERT INTO TheTable.....", , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT @@Identity", , adCmdText)
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value
```

`cn` being a valid ADO connection, `@@Identity` will return the last
`Identity` (Autonumber) inserted on this connection.

Note that `@@Identity` might be troublesome because the last generated value may not be the one you are interested in. For the Access database engine, consider a `VIEW` that joins two tables, both of which have the `IDENTITY` property, and you `INSERT INTO` the `VIEW`. For SQL Server, consider if there are triggers that in turn insert records into another table that also has the `IDENTITY` property.

BTW `DMax` would not work as if someone else inserts a record just after you've inserted one but before your `Dmax` function finishes excecuting, then you would get their record.

Comment: DAO can do SELECT @@IDENTITY, too -- you don't need ADO. I do this all the time: lngID = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0), where "db" is the same database variable that was used to execute the insert. I no longer open recordsets and Add for this.

Comment: This does not work for me. I made an insert into a SQL Server Table with dao. I get a error: "Record is deleted" (3167)

Answer (score 58):

In your example, because you use CurrentDB to execute your INSERT you've made it harder for yourself. Instead, this will work:

```
  Dim query As String
  Dim newRow As Long  ' note change of data type
  Dim db As DAO.Database

  query = "INSERT INTO InvoiceNumbers (date) VALUES (" & NOW() & ");"
  Set db = CurrentDB
  db.Execute(query)
  newRow = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
  Set db = Nothing
```

I used to do INSERTs by opening an `AddOnly` recordset and picking up the ID from there, but this here is a lot more efficient. And note that it doesn't require `ADO`.

Comment: and it works even when the recordset is a SQL Server linked table ! Wonderful !

Comment: you might also add dbFailOnError as an option to the Execute.
Otherwise Access won't say anything if it fails. -----
db.Execute query, dbFailOnError

Comment: @iDevlop SQL Server supports [the `SELECT @@IDENTITY` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx). It would be interesting to see what happens in other linked table types such as Excel, or other RDBMSs such as Oracle or MySQL.

Comment: This does not work for me. I made an insert into a SQL Server Table with dao. I always get 0 in newRow.

Answer (score 4):

This is an adaptation from my code for you.  I was inspired from [developpez.com](http://access.developpez.com/faq/?page=SQL#DiffRstSQL) (Look in the page for : "*Pour insérer des données, vaut-il mieux passer par un RecordSet ou par une requête de type INSERT ?*"). They explain (with a little French). This way is much faster than the one upper. In the example, this way was 37 times faster. Try it.

```
Const tableName As String = "InvoiceNumbers"
Const columnIdName As String = "??"
Const columnDateName As String = "date"

Dim rsTable As DAO.recordSet
Dim recordId as long

Set rsTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tableName)
Call rsTable .AddNew
recordId = CLng(rsTable (columnIdName)) ' Save your Id in a variable
rsTable (columnDateName) = Now()        ' Store your data
rsTable .Update

recordSet.Close
```

LeCygne

Comment: Could you please identify which particular example it is "37 times faster" than?

Comment: This does not work for me. I made an insert into a SQL Server Table with dao. recordId  is always the same (1).

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Function addInsert(Media As String, pagesOut As Integer) As Long


    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblenccomponent")
    With rst
        .AddNew
        !LeafletCode = LeafletCode
        !LeafletName = LeafletName
        !UNCPath = "somePath\" + LeafletCode + ".xml"
        !Media = Media
        !CustomerID = cboCustomerID.Column(0)
        !PagesIn = PagesIn
        !pagesOut = pagesOut
        addInsert = CLng(rst!enclosureID) 'ID is passed back to calling routine
        .Update
    End With
    rst.Close

End Function
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the original question. Please add context to see how this fits?

Comment: This answer is unclear. Please add explanations. Not all of us know **everything** about vba.

Comment: The commented line shows where the ID is collected. You would have to change the names to match your table ID. FORMAT: RecordName!IDName

Comment: Although poorly explained, this format worked for me as it was closest to the structure of the method that I was already using.

Comment: This does not work for me. I made an insert into a SQL Server Table with dao. addInsert is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the examples immediately above didn't work for me.  Opening a recordset on the table and adding a record does work to add the record, except:

```
myLong = CLng(rs!AutoNumberField)
```

returns Null if put between rs.AddNew and rs.Update.  If put after rs.Update, it does return something, but it's always wrong, and always the same incorrect value.  Looking at the table directly after adding the new record shows an autonumber field value different than the one returned by the above statement.

```
myLong = DLookup("AutoNumberField","TableName","SomeCriteria")
```

will work properly, as long as it's done after rs.Update, and there are any other fields which can uniquely identify the record.

Comment: I made an insert into a SQL Server Table with dao. This is the only thing that works for me. But I Use DMax instead of DLookup.