# Getting last autonumber in access

Tags: c#

I am trying to get last auto number after inserting record into access database. I am getting zero. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried to google but could not find any simple example which I can use to understand.

```
// Database was opened before.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Insert is working fine.
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", con);
id = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // id shows zero in debug
```

Comment: Searching for [access SELECT @@IDENTITY](http://www.bing.com/search?q=access+SELECT+%40%40IDENTITY) -  gives you [HOW TO: Retrieve the Identity Value While Inserting Records into Access Database By Using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815629) - which uses `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` (which returns number of affected rows, not a result ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is meant for doing catalog type operations (creating/deleting objects and so forth) and `update/insert/delete` operations (note that `select` is not in that list).

For the `update/insert/delete`, it returns the number of rows affected.

If you want to *select* something from the database, you will need to get a result set to see what it returns (see [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example).

Altenatively, [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can execute a command and return the first column of the first row, which seems to be what you're after here.

Comment: +1 `ExecuteScalar` is the MSDN recommended way of getting the value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For someone like me, the syntax is id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628267/autonumber-value-of-last-inserted-row-ms-access-vba):

```
cn.Execute "INSERT INTO TheTable.....", , cmd+ adExecuteNoRecords
Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT @@Identity", , cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

> If DAO use

```
RS.Move 0, RS.LastModified
lngID = RS!AutoNumberFieldName
```

> If ADO use

```
cn.Execute "INSERT INTO TheTable.....", , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT @@Identity", , adCmdText)
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value
```

cn being a valid ADO connection, @@Identity will return the last Identity (Autonumber) inserted on this connection.