# Returning id from access database

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, phpmyadmin

this is my code that is inserting data into an access database using php.

```
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" . realpath(‘my access path’) . ";";
// Open the connection to the database
$conn->open($connStr);


$query = “my insert query here which inserts into theaccess database fine”

$query2 = "select @@IDENTITY"

try{
$rs = $conn->execute($query);

$idReturned = $conn->lastInsertId();

echo json_encode($idReturned); 

} catch(com_exception $e){
        echo($e);
    }
```

I’m trying to get the returned id but all I am getting is the below error :

> exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: ADODB.Connection
>   Description: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable
>   range, or are in conflict with one another.' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\agency\createnewvaluation.php:132 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\agency\createnewvaluation.php(132):
>   com->lastInsertId() #1 {main}

Comment: I'm curious if you looked at the other answers on this site, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916552/getting-last-autonumber-in-access?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes and im still having lots of trouble :(

Comment: The exception reads: "com->lastinsertId , in the code you have conn_>lastinsertId.  Typo?

Comment: I think thats just because lastinsertid is a function of COM or PDO, I see no typo.

Comment: execute the $query2 which will return the last inserted id from access.

Comment: $idquery = "select @@IDENTITY";
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
$rs2 = $conn->execute($idquery);
echo json_encode($rs2);

just returns blank object

Comment: use fetchAll() before passing to json_encode

Answer (score 0):

I went though the results manually and got the code myself

```
if($dbh->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME) == 'pgsql') {

} elseif($dbh->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME) == 'odbc') {
  $sb = $dbh->prepare('SELECT @@IDENTITY AS lastID');
  $sb->execute();
  $row = $sb->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $arr = array("ref" => $row["lastID"]);
                echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
                $arr = array("ref" => "error");
                echo json_encode($arr);
}
```