# Autonumber value of last inserted row - MS Access / VBA (Value=0)

Tags: ms-access, vba, autonumber

I need to get the Autonumbered ID of the last record inserted into a table (through INSERT INTO command)

I have seen some methods in the forum that looks to work for most of the community but not in my case:
[Autonumber value of last inserted row - MS Access / VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628267/autonumber-value-of-last-inserted-row-ms-access-vba)

```
Dim miDDBB As DAO.Database
.....
StrSQL = " INSERT INTO DG_tb_Main " ......   
Set miDDBB = CurrentDb
miDDBB.Execute (StrSQL)
newRow = miDDBB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
Set db = Nothing
```

When using this code I always get the 'newRow' value as '0'.
I have checked the SQL expresion and works fine, insterting the new record into the table.
¿What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Is this your actual code? `Set db = Nothing` vs. `miDDBB` before is suspect. -- Is `DG_tb_Main` a linked table? If so, from where?

Answer (score 0):

Study your own reference again.

You have DAO, but use the method for ADO.

Comment: Thanks Gustav for your quick reply.