# How to get the last insert Id in Ms Access using vb6.0

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am using VB6.0 for an assignment, it was so long that I used this. I'm trying to get the last inserted Id. My query is giving me the first row ID

I am using OLEDB. I have used some code but it is returning the first-row id.

```
Network
    rec.Open "staff_profile", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    With rec
    .AddNew
      ![fields] = values
    .Save
      'rec.Update
  lastID = rec("ID")
  FileCopy frmRegister.cdl.FileName, fname & transcode & ".jpg"
    'return ID
    MsgBox "Record Saved Successfully " & lastID, vbInformation, "Trillium"
```

I want the result to give me the last inserted id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autonumber value of last inserted row - MS Access / VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628267/autonumber-value-of-last-inserted-row-ms-access-vba)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
With rec
    .AddNew
      ![fields] = values
    .Save
    .MoveLast
    lastID = !ID.Value
End With
```